# What are the drawbacks of immutable types?

Tags: c#, immutability

I see myself using more and more immutable types *when the instances of the class are not expected to be changed*. It requires more work (see example below), but makes it easier to use the types in a multithreaded environment.

At the same time, I rarely see immutable types in other applications, even when mutability wouldn't benefit anyone.

**Question:** Why immutable types are so rarely used in other applications?

- Is this because it's longer to write code for an immutable type,
- Or am I missing something and there are some important drawbacks when using immutable types?

### Example from real life

Let's say you get `Weather` from a RESTful API like that:

```cs
public Weather FindWeather(string city)
{
    // TODO: Load the JSON response from the RESTful API and translate it into an instance
    // of the Weather class.
}
```

What we would generally see is (new lines and comments removed to shorten the code):

```cs
public sealed class Weather
{
    public City CorrespondingCity { get; set; }
    public SkyState Sky { get; set; } // Example: SkyState.Clouds, SkyState.HeavySnow, etc.
    public int PrecipitationRisk { get; set; }
    public int Temperature { get; set; }
}
```

On the other hand, I would write it this way, given that getting a `Weather` from the API, then modifying it would be weird: changing `Temperature` or `Sky` wouldn't change the weather in real world, and changing `CorrespondingCity` doesn't make sense neither.

```cs
public sealed class Weather
{
    private readonly City correspondingCity;
    private readonly SkyState sky;
    private readonly int precipitationRisk;
    private readonly int temperature;

    public Weather(City correspondingCity, SkyState sky, int precipitationRisk,
        int temperature)
    {
        this.correspondingCity = correspondingCity;
        this.sky = sky;
        this.precipitationRisk = precipitationRisk;
        this.temperature = temperature;
    }

    public City CorrespondingCity { get { return this.correspondingCity; } }
    public SkyState Sky { get { return this.sky; } }
    public int PrecipitationRisk { get { return this.precipitationRisk; } }
    public int Temperature { get { return this.temperature; } }
}
```

Comment: “It requires more work” – citation required. In my experience it requires *less* work.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: by *more work*, I mean more code to write to create an immutable class. The example from my question illustrates this, with 7 lines for a mutable class and 19 for an immutable one.

Comment: You can reduce code typing by using Code Snippets feature in Visual Studio if you are using it. You can create your custom snippets and let the IDE define you the field and the property at the same time with a few keys. Immutable types are essential for multithreading and used extensively in languages like Scala.

Comment: @Mert: Code snippets are great for simple things. Writing a code snippet which will build a full class with comments of fields and properties and correct ordering would not be an easy task.

Comment: I disagree with the example given, the immutable version is doing more and different things. You could remove the instance-level variables by declaring properties with accessors `{get; private set;}`, and even the mutable one should have a constructor, because all of those fields should always be set and why would you not enforce that? Making those two perfectly reasonable changes brings them to feature and LoC parity.

Comment: @MainMa The example does not represent the best available approach though. The immutable code can be made (almost) as short as the mutable one, and many examples are indeed shorter then their mutable counterpart.

Comment: @MainMa I didn't mean to create a snippet for creating a class for you, but a snippet for creating a private field and a readonly property at the same time.

Comment: The gist of it is that we have a long history of imperative programming that can be traced back to C. (Of course, imperative programming was around since the assembly days, but C is probably the biggest influence on the syntax and idioms of your average object-oriented language.)

Comment: Drawback: Not mutable.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I program in C# and Objective-C. I really like immutable typing, but in real life I've been always forced to limit its usage, mainly for data types, for the following reasons:

1. **Implementation effort** comparing to mutable types. With an immutable type, you would need to have a constructor requiring arguments for all properties. Your example is a good one. Try imagining that you have 10 classes, each having 5-10 properties. To make things easier, you might need to have a builder class to construct or create modified immutable instances in a manner similar to `StringBuilder` or `UriBuilder` in C#, or `WeatherBuilder` in your case. This is the main reason for me as many classes I design are  not worth such an effort.
2. **Consumer usability**. An immutable type is more difficult to use in comparison to mutable type. Instantiation requires initialising all values. Immutability also means that we cannot pass the instance to a method to modify its value without using a builder, and if we need to have a builder then the drawback is in my (1).
3. **Compatibility with the language's framework.** Many of the data frameworks require mutable types and default constructors to operate. For example, you cannot do nested LINQ-to-SQL query with immutable types, and you cannot bind properties to be edited in editors  such as Windows Forms' TextBox.

In short, immutability is good for objects that behave like values, or only have a few properties. Before making anything immutable, you must consider the effort needed and the usability of the class itself after making it immutable.

Comment: "The instantiation need all values beforehand.": Also a mutable type does, unless you accept the risk of having an object with uninitialized fields floating around...

Comment: @Giorgio For mutable type, default constructor should initialise the instance to the default state and the state of the instance can be altered later after instantiation.

Comment: For an immutable type you can have the same default constructor, and make a copy later using another constructor. If the default values are valid for the mutable type, they should be valid for the immutable type too because in both cases you are modelling the same entity. Or what is the difference?

Comment: One more thing to consider is what the type represents. Data contracts don't make for good immutable types because of all these points, but service types that get initialized with dependencies or read only data and then perform operations are great for immutability because the operations will perform consistently and the state of the service cannot be changed to risk that.

Comment: @Giorgio The point is the consumer's convenience. Making a copy is technically another instantiation, and it is also quite tedious if you use constructor. Fluent interface might be really helpful in some language for making immutable type manipulated copy, but the usability is still lower than simple assignment, take time to implement and definitely has more or less performance impact comparing to plain mutable type.

Comment: I currently code in F#, where immutability is the default (hence easier to implement). I find that your point 3 is the big hurdle. As soon as you use most standard .Net libraries, you will need to jump through hoops. (And if they use reflection and thus bypass immutability... argh!)

Answer (score 5):

Just generally immutable types created in languages that don't revolve around immutability will tend to cost more developer time to create as well as potentially use if they require some "builder" type of object to express desired changes (this does not mean that the overall work will be more, but there is a cost upfront in these cases). Also regardless of whether the language makes it really easy to create immutable types or not, it'll tend to always require some processing and memory overhead for non-trivial data types.

**Making Functions Devoid of Side Effects**

If you are working in languages that don't revolve around immutability, then I think the pragmatic approach is not to seek to make every single data type immutable. A potentially far more productive mindset which gives you many of the same benefits is to focus on maximizing the number of functions in your system that cause *zero side effects*.

As a simple example, if you have a function which causes a side effect like this:

```cpp
// Make 'x' the absolute value of itself.
void make_abs(int& x);
```

Then we don't need an immutable integer data type that forbids operators like post-initialization assignment to make that function avoid side effects. We can simply do this:

```cpp
// Returns the absolute value of 'x'.
int abs(int x);
```

Now the function doesn't mess with `x` or anything outside of its scope, and in this trivial case we might have even shaved some cycles by avoiding any overhead associated with the indirection/aliasing. At the very least the second version shouldn't be more computationally expensive than the first.

**Things That Are Expensive to Copy in Full**

Of course most cases aren't this trivial if we want to avoid making a function cause side effects. A complex real-world use case might be more like this:

```cpp
// Transforms the vertices of the specified mesh by
// the specified transformation matrix.
void transform(Mesh& mesh, Matrix4f matrix);
```

At which point the mesh might require a couple hundred megabytes of memory with over a hundred thousand polygons, even more vertices and edges, multiple texture maps, morph targets, etc. It'd be really expensive to copy that whole mesh just to make this `transform` function free of side effects, like so:

```cpp
// Returns a new version of the mesh whose vertices been 
// transformed by the specified transformation matrix.
Mesh transform(Mesh mesh, Matrix4f matrix);
```

And it's in these cases where copying something in its entirety would normally be an epic overhead where I've found it useful to turn `Mesh` into a persistent data structure and an immutable type with the analogical "builder" to create modified versions of it so that it can simply shallow copy and reference count parts which aren't unique. It's all with the focus of being able to write mesh functions which are free of side effects.

**Persistent Data Structures**

And in these cases where copying everything is so incredibly expensive, I found the effort of designing an immutable `Mesh` to really pay off even though it had a slightly steep cost upfront, because it didn't just simplify thread safety. It also simplified non-destructive editing (allowing the user to layer mesh operations without modifying his original copy), undo systems (now the undo system can just store an immutable copy of the mesh prior to the changes made by an operation without blowing up memory use), and exception-safety (now if an exception occurs in the above function, the function doesn't have to roll back and undo all of its side effects since it didn't cause any to begin with).

I can confidently say in these cases that the time required to make these hefty data structures immutable saved more time than it cost, since I've compared the maintenance costs of these new designs against former ones which revolved around mutability and functions causing side effects, and the former mutable designs cost far more time and were far more prone to human error, especially in areas that are really tempting for developers to neglect during crunch time, like exception-safety.

So I do think immutable data types really pay off in these cases, but not everything has to be made immutable in order to make the majority of the functions in your system free of side effects. Many things are cheap enough to just copy in full. Also many real-world applications will need to cause some side effects here and there (at the very least like saving a file), but typically there are far more functions which could be devoid of side effects.

The point of having some immutable data types to me is to make sure we can write the maximum number of functions to be free of side effects without incurring epic overhead in the form of deep copying massive data structures left and right in full when only small portions of them need to be modified. Having persistent data structures around in those cases then ends up becoming an optimization detail to allow us to write our functions to be free of side effects without paying an epic cost to doing so.

**Immutable Overhead**

Now conceptually the mutable versions will always have an edge in efficiency. There is always that computational overhead associated with immutable data structures. But I found it a worthy exchange in the cases I described above, and you can focus on making the overhead sufficiently minimal in nature. I prefer that type of approach where correctness becomes easy and optimization becomes harder rather than optimization being easier but correctness becoming harder. It's not nearly as demoralizing to have code that functions perfectly correctly in need of some more tune ups over code that doesn't function correctly in the first place no matter how quickly it achieves its incorrect results.

Answer (score 3):

The only drawback I can think of is that in theory use of immutable data may be slower than mutable ones - it is slower to create a new instance, and collect previous one than to modify existing one.

The other "problem" is that you can't only use immutable types. In the end you have to describe the state and you have to use mutable types to do so - without changing state you can't do any work.

But still general rule is to use immutable types wherever you can and make types mutable only when there really is a reason to do so...

And to answer the question "*Why immutable types are so rarely used in other applications?*" - I really don't think they are... wherever you look everyone recommends making your classes as immutable as they can be... for example: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=29

Comment: Both of your problems aren't in Haskell though.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine Could you elaborate?

Comment: The slowness is not true thanks to a smart compiler. And in Haskell, even I/O is through an immutable API.

Comment: A more fundamental problem than speed is that it is difficult for immutable objects to maintain an identity while their state changes.  If a mutable `Car` object is continuously updated with the location of a particular physical automobile, then if I have a reference to that object I can find out the whereabouts of that automobile quickly and easily.  If `Car` were immutable, finding the current whereabouts would likely be much harder.

Comment: You have to code quite smartly sometimes for the compiler to figure out that there's no reference to the previous object left behind and thus can modify it in place, or do deforestation transforms, et al. Especially in larger programs. And as @supercat says, identity can indeed become a problem.

Comment: @Macke: I wish .NET had a non-copyable-reference type would only be usable in contexts where the compiler could show that it would only be usable once [e.g. `Thing.WithX(123).WithY(456).WithZ(789)`, the `WithX` might have to produce a new object, but the `WithY` and `WithZ` could know that they could safely mutate the objects they were given].  Such types could ideally specify a type to which they should be implicitly converted if an attempt is made to store them.  I know of no intention to add such a feature, though.

Comment: @supercat: Like C++11's rvalue references?

Comment: Something that would be to a heap object reference what a C++ rvalue reference would be to a pointer.  The .NET framework does have C++-style references (called "byrefs") but a byref to a reference point is like a C++ rvalue reference to a pointer, rather than a reference to the pointer's target.

Answer (score 0):

To model any real-world system which where things can change, mutable state will need to be encoded somewhere, somehow.  There are three main ways an object can hold mutable state:

- Using a mutable reference to an immutable object
- Using an immutable reference to a mutable object
- Using a mutable reference to a mutable object

Using first makes it easy for an object to make an immutable snapshot of the present state.  Using the second makes it easy for an object to create a live view of the present state.  Using the third can sometimes make certain actions more efficient in cases where there's little expected need for immutable snapshots nor live views.

Beyond the fact that updating state stored using a mutable reference to an immutable object is often slower than updating state stored using a mutable object, using a mutable reference will require one to forgo the possibility of constructing a cheap live view of the state.  If one won't need to create a live view, that's not a problem; if, however, one would need to create a live view, an inability to use an immutable reference will make all operations with the view--*both reads and writes*--much slower than they otherwise would be.  If the need for immutable snapshots exceeds the need for live views, the improved performance of immutable snapshots may justify the performance hit for live views, but if one needs live views and doesn't need snapshots, using immutable references to mutable objects is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

In your case the answer is mainly because C# has poor support for Immutability ...

It would be great if:

- everything will be immutable by default unless noted otherwise (ie with a 'mutable' keyword), mixing immutable and mutable types is confusing
- mutating methods (`With`) will be automatically available - though this can already be achieved see [With](https://github.com/kofifus/With)
- there will be a way to saying the result of a specific method call (ie `ImmutableList<T>.Add`) cannot be discarded or at least will produce a warning
- And mainly if the compiler could as much as possible ensure immutability where requested (see https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/159)

Comment: Re the third point, ReSharper has a `MustUseReturnValueAttribute` custom attribute that does exactly that. `PureAttribute` has the same effect and is even better for this.

Answer (score -1):

> Why immutable types are so rarely used in other applications?

Ignorance? Inexperience?

Immutable objects are widely regarded as superior today, but it's a relatively recent development. Engineers who haven't kept up to date, or are simply stuck in 'what they know' won't use them. And it does take a bit of design changes to use them effectively. If the apps are old, or the engineers weak in design skills then using them might be awkward or otherwise troublesome.

Comment: "Engineers who haven't kept up to date": One could say that an engineer should also learn about non-mainstream technologies. The idea of immutability is only recently becoming mainstream, but it is a quite old idea and is supported (if not enforced) by older languages like Scheme, SML, Haskell. So anyone who is used to looking beyond mainstream languages could have learned about it even 30 years ago.

Comment: @Giorgio: in some countries, many *engineers* still write C# code without LINQ, without FP, without iterators and without generics, so actually, they somehow missed everything which happened with C# since 2003. If they don't even know their language of preference, I hardly imagine them to know any non-mainstream language.

Comment: @MainMa: Good that you wrote the word _engineers_ in italics.

Comment: @Giorgio: in my country, they are also called *architects*, *consultants*, and lots of other vainglorious terms, never written in italics. In the company I'm currently working at, I'm called *analyst developer*, and I'm expected to spend my time writing CSS for crappy legacy HTML code. Job titles are disturbing on so many levels.

Comment: @MainMa: I agree. Titles like engineer or consultant are often just buzzwords with no widely-accepted meaning. They are often used to make someone or their position more important / prestigious than it actually is.

Comment: @giorgio - sure, but even though they were available in more esoteric languages, they've only vaguely been considered best practice recently. Before, they were a neat trick that were not clearly preferable in most scenarios.

Comment: @Telastyn: I am not sure if I would consider these languages esoteric. Especially Lisp dialects have a long history of applications and, even though they allow mutability, they always promoted immutability / referential transparency (I remember learning about this during my computer science study back in 1991.) Of course, certain branches of the industry (especially those using imperative languages) recognized the advantages of immutability later than others, but I would not generalize too much.